# How to add default value selected in dropdownlist with enum?

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am new to yii2 and trying to get around. I have a dropdownlist whose values in the database are enum. So when the crud was created the dropdownlist had the enum values.

But I want to keep one value selected as default in the drop down list.
My form code is below:

`<?= $form->field($model, 'priotiy_level')->dropDownList([ 'low' => 'Low', 'medium' => 'Medium', 'high' => 'High', ], ['prompt' => 'Select Priority Level']) ?>`

Instead of the prompt, I want to have medium as a selected value. Can someone please help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After initialization of the $model instance in your controller set the attribute and then pass $model to view.

```
$model->priority_level = 'medium';
```

Comment: Tried that. But it still doesn't select medium as default.

Comment: There must be something wrong on your side. I've just double checked it and it works.

Comment: public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Tasks();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
   
   
   $model->start_date = date('Y-m-d'); //to get default date
   $model->priority_level = 'medium';
   $model->save();
   
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->Task_ID]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

Comment: Initialisation is `$model = new Tasks;` so after this line.

Answer (score 1):

As @Bizley said, you need to set the value of the attribute in your Controller. In Yii2, you can do that with in one line:

```
public function actionSomething {
    $model = new MyClass(['priotiy_level' => 'medium']);

    // code

    return $this->render('something', [
        'model' => $model
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give **class** to your **dropdownList** :

Ex.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'priotiy_level')->dropDownList([ 'low' => 'Low', 'medium' => 'Medium', 'high' => 'High', ], ['class' => 'priority_list','prompt' => 'Select Priority Level']) ?>
```

Give Default value using **Java Script** or **Jquery**

Ex.

```
<script>
$(".priority_list").val('medium'); // assing value using jquery
</script>
```

You can also use ID:

Ex.

```
 <script>
    var temp=document.getElementById('project-industry_id');
    temp.value='medium';
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to previous answers you can also use `default` validator:

```
class SomeActiveRecord extends ActiveRecord {

    // ...
    function rules(){

        return [
            ['priotiy_level', 'default', 'value' => 'medium']

            // set "username" and "email" as null if they are empty
            [['username', 'email'], 'default'],

            // set "level" to be 1 if it is empty
            ['level', 'default', 'value' => 1],
        ];

    }

}
```

More details see here: [Handling Empty Inputs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#handling-empty-inputs).

This code sets default value for the all actions/forms. If you need different default values on different forms, can be used also [scenarios of validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#declaring-rules).